# Powershell join lines

Tags: powershell

I have text file(s) that look like below:

1.

SometextSometextSometextSometext

2.

 
SometextSometextSometextSometext

3.

SometextSometextSometextSometext

4.

 
SometextSometextSometextSometext

I need to remove the carriage return between the number and the text below it and there needs to be a space between the number(.) and moved text as below:

Right now I'm trying:

```
$x =  Get-Content *FILENAME*
$x |  Foreach-Object {$_ | select-string "^\d{1,2}\.\s+" }
```

(Note: I can match on select-string "^\d{1,2}.\s+" but after than don't know how to remove the line break or join the files)

**Final Outcome I'm trying for:**

1. SometextSometextSometextSometext
2. SometextSometextSometextSometext
3. SometextSometextSometextSometext
4. SometextSometextSometextSometext

Comment: I don't think there is any solution to your problem. All hope is lost

Comment: Amazing how what seems like a simple question gets 5 different answers, and I'll bet they all probably work (for the most part at least).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Text is fun to play with

Comment: Andy Arismnedi, I know you are trying to be funny, but online it just comes off as dumb :(  Good luck.

Comment: @niz100 its a stack overflow thing, you'll get it after being on this site for awhile

Comment: Ok.  I which case you're not lame :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the pipeline only works one line at a time, it's probably easiest to save the number in a buffer, and output it when you get to the next line:

```
$x | Foreach-Object {if($_ -match "^\d{1,2}\.\s+"){$num = $_}else{$num+$_;$num="";} }
```

Comment: The pipe only processes one *object* at a time, but if that object is a multiline string you're effectively processing multiple lines at a time.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Fair enough, but he won't get multiline objects using get-content.

Comment: He will with -ReadCount: -ReadCount <Int64>; Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.

Answer (score 6):

```powershell
$x = Get-Content $filename -Raw
$x -replace '(\d{1,2}\.)\s*\r?\n(.+?)(\r?\n|$){2,}','$1 $2$3'
```

### How this works:

1. Calling `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` parameter returns the file as a single string instead of individual lines. In this case, since you're working with line breaks, it's easier to see it all as one string.
2. The regular expression works as follows:

   1. Find 1 or 2 digits followed by a `.`, and capture this in group 1.
   2. Continue matching on any amount of whitespace, followed by an optional carriage return, followed by a single linefeed (this should work for windows/non-windows line endings).
   3. Match 1 or more characters (non-greedy) and capture in group 2.
   4. Match or CRLF or LF combination *or* match the end of the string, 2 or more times, but *only capture the first instance* in group 3.
3. So now we have 3 captured groups: the number and the `.` after it, the line you want, and a single line ending if it existed.
4. We replace the entire thing we matched with group 1, a single space, then group 2 and group 3.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try something shorter:

```
Get-Content $my_file -ReadCount 3 | ForEach{$_ -Join " "}
```

That splits it into groups of lines, and joins them with a space. Not sure why it's 3 and not 2 to be honest, I just know it works when I tested it against the sample you provided. Below is my test (I saved that to a text file at C:\Temp\Test.txt):

```
PS C:\> gc C:\temp\test.txt -ReadCount 3 | %{$_  -join " "}
1. SometextSometextSometextSometext 
2. SometextSometextSometextSometext 
3. SometextSometextSometextSometext 
4. SometextSometextSometextSometext
```

**Edit:** Oh, duh, it's 3 not 2 because there's blank lines in the text file. So I suppose technically this is adding a space at the end of each piece of text. That could be avoided by filtering for blank lines:

```
Get-Content $my_file -ReadCount 3 | ForEach{($_ | Where{![String]::IsNullorEmpty($_)}) -Join " "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. It uses the buffering approach, but instead of `+=` to concatenate onto a string, it uses a StringBuilder, which can perform better. (See [this blog post](http://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/another-take-on-using-the-operator/))

```
$source = (
"1.",
"SometextSometextSometextSometext",
"",
"2.",
"SometextSometextSometextSometext",
"3.",
"",
"SometextSometextSometextSometext"
);


$stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

$source | % {
    if ($_ -match [regex]'^\d+\.') {
        $null = $stringBuilder.Append("{0} " -f $_)
    }
    if ($_ -match [regex]'^[A-Za-z]') {
            $null = $stringBuilder.Append($_)
            $stringBuilder.ToString();
            $stringBuilder.Length = 0;
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> 1. SometextSometextSometextSometext
> 2. SometextSometextSometextSometext
> 3. SometextSometextSometextSometext

Answer (score 1):

```
PS > Get-Content -ReadCount 3 FILENAME | Write-Host
1. SometextSometextSometextSometext
2. SometextSometextSometextSometext
3. SometextSometextSometextSometext
4. SometextSometextSometextSometext
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$lines = Get-Content $my_file

for ($i = 0; $i -le $lines.Count; $i+=3) {
    if ($lines[$i] -match '^\d+?\.') {
        $lines[$i].TrimEnd() + ' ' + $lines[$i + 1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with replace option.

```
$FirstLast = "Mohammed
Junaid"


$FirstLast -replace ("`n"," ")
```

The result will be

```
"Mohammed Junaid"
```